# How to slice a string when using the useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component, state-management

I have a component with the following handler:

```
<MyComponent onKeyDown={handler} />
```

The handler looks like this:

```
const handler = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
    const slicedString = input.slice(0, -1);
    setInput(slicedString);
  }
};
```

And this is my useState hook:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');
```

I want to slice the last character of the input when `'Backspace'` is pressed `onKeyDown` event.

The `slicedString` gets updated when backspace is pressed but the `input` state stays the same. I know that the spread operator has to be used for objects and arrays but how can I update the state when a string is used?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues with what you have posted.  How are you reading/displaying the `input` state?

Comment: As mentioned in my post - the slicedString gets updated, but setInput has no effect on my input.

Comment: I understand that, but how do you know.  Can you show the code where you're using `input`.

Comment: Are you sure that your handler is being invoked? Perhaps you can add a `console.log` inside the definition and make sure that it is being called

Comment: Yes it is invoked, that's the reason I know that the state is not updated. Added console.logs etc.

Comment: This is really weird, everything looks fine and should work if your handler is being executed, You can try with `setInput(prev => prev.slice(0, -1))` but it would be even more confusing to me if that works, because `.slice` returns new string and is completely fine to do it in a way you did it.

Comment: Could you add an example in which this problem occurs?